# Link to an img inside <td> not working

Tags: php, html, image, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a huge issue with clicking and opening an image inside table. I created mysql database and implemented via php in table on my site. Everything works just fine except images. They are showing up as a thumbails on table (and they should be, because I put height very small) but when I want to click on them, nothing happens, it just don't wanna go on that place where the image is located (even though the link to the image appears on bottom of the browser and my cursor goes in "link" mode).

That part of my PHP code:

```
echo "<table class=table>                        
         <tr>  
             <th><b>ID:</b></th> 
             <th><b>Ime:</b></th>                             
             <th><b>Dimenzije-cm:</b></th> 
             <th><b>Kol.po-m2:</b></th> 
             <th><b>Težina-kg/m2:</b></th> 
             <th><b>Na paleti-m2:</b></th> 
             <th><b>Slike:</b></th>"; 

while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){ 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['ime'] . "</td>";                                 
    echo "<td>" . $record['dimenzije-cm'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['kol.po-m2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['tezina-kg/m2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $record['na paleti-m2'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td><a href=" . $record['images'] . " > <img src=" . $record['images'] . " height=30px;></a></td>"; 
}
```

Here is image how it looks like live:

https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xta1/v/t34.0-12/11262253_1414454508878108_1351851566_n.jpg?oh=ad86bddc6f63af616e71793f3dd1e207&oe=555F5832

https://scontent-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xta1/v/t34.0-12/11276070_1414454165544809_752028311_n.jpg?oh=30f5febf7695ac5320d696b569348df0&oe=555FAA1A

As you can see in my code, link for `<img src` and `<a href` is the same (the image is the same one - 1.jpg) and the location is good, but it don't want to click and go on image inside localhost/1.jpg)..

I created the site using Bootstrap, so maybe there is something in css for table imgs that creates the problem? Help me please..

And yes, I tried creating new .php file and just c/p PHP code in it, and it works perfectly.. It opens my image when I click on it just as it should be.

[image]

Comment: use `print screen` button to take screen shoot

Comment: Make sure your linking the images correctly!! The directory might be wrong...anyway just a suggestion! Stupid stuff like that always happens

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
echo "<td><a href=" . $record['images'] . " > 
                                <img src=" . $record['images'] . " height=30px;></a></td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td><a href=\"" . $record['images'] . "\" > 
                                <img src=\"" . $record['images'] . "\" height=\"30\" /></a></td>";
```

note the escaped `\"`

Comment: it still doesn't work :( :( Here is link for the css aswel: http://speedy.sh/xEyy8/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @MirzaAlibegović maybe try adding a closing  `</tr>` I just noticed that is missing

Comment: not working after closing </tr> .. can you please check my css, i really think that it is something inside that css that makes the problem, because i copy/pasted exactly the same php code in blank new page and it worked just fine..

Comment: save me bro please :(